# Re-write Python function with multiple if-elif conditions into Scala if-else functional style

Tags: scala, unit-testing, if-statement, functional-programming

I'm currently writing a Scala Object that converts time 24hr format (i.e. 00:00 - 23:59) into Time As Words (i.e. Eight o'clock, Half past eight, Quarter to nine etc). I have written most of the code and I'm busy trying to decide on the most suitable functional and testable style to create smaller functions to handle the multiple conditions which need to return a string based on a Map lookup of the integers word equivalent, and return a string based on the the time of day. Does the following approach meet functional programming style as the function will be split out as the logic is different for each of the following three grouped conditions.

So my initial idea is to create smaller functions of the current time_conversion so that the following conditions are split out due to logic and test ability:

Suggested Three Smaller Functions:

1. Midday and Midnight exception
2. Minutes (0,15,30,45) as the string pattern is similar and a Map lookup can be used to generate the output string (i.e. o'clock, Quater past, Half past, Quarter to).
3. Hours2 + Minutes > 30 due pattern match to generate output string

Python version of word lookup:

```
words_dict = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five',
                  6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine', 10: 'ten',
                  11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen',
                  14: 'fourteen', 16: 'sixteen', 17: 'seventeen',
                  18: 'eighteen', 19: 'nineteen', 20: 'twenty',
                  21: 'twenty one', 22: 'twenty two', 23: 'twenty three',
                  24: 'twenty four', 25: 'twenty five', 26: 'twenty six',
                  27: 'twenty seven', 28: 'twenty eight', 29: 'twenty nine'}
```

Python version of if-elif-else conditions:

```
def time_conversion(words_dict, hours, minutes, period):
    """Return time as words
    based on relevant condition"""
    if hours == 12:
        hours2 = words_dict.get(1)
    else:
        hours2 = words_dict.get(hours+1)
    if hours == 12 and minutes == 0 and period == 'before midday':
        time_words = 'Midnight'
    elif hours == 12 and minutes == 0 and period == 'after midday':
        time_words = 'Midday'
    elif minutes == 0:
        time_words = "{0} o'clock {1}.".format(str(words_dict.get(hours)).title(),
                                               period)
    elif minutes == 15:
        time_words = "Quarter past {0} {1}.".format(words_dict.get(hours),
                                                    period)
    elif minutes == 30:
        time_words = "Half past {0} {1}.".format(words_dict.get(hours),
                                                 period)
    elif minutes == 45:
        time_words = "Quarter to {0} {1}.".format(hours2,
                                                  period)
    elif minutes < 30:
        min_str = words_dict.get(minutes).capitalize()
        min_num = "" if minutes == 1 else "s"
        time_words = "{0} minute{1} past {2} {3}.".format(min_str,
                                                          min_num,
                                                          words_dict.get(hours),
                                                          period)
    else:
        min_str = words_dict.get(60 - minutes).capitalize()
        min_num = "" if 60 - minutes == 1 else "s"
        time_words = '{0} minute{1} to {2} {3}.'.format(min_str,
                                                        min_num,
                                                        hours2,
                                                        period)
    return time_words
```

Current Scala Object.

```
package time

/**
  * Created by PeterW on 6/14/2017.
  */
object TimeAsWords extends App {
  // Input string argument is based on 24hr format 23:59
  val InputTime = args(0)

  // regular expression string
  val Exp24hr = """^(([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)|23:59)$"""

  // a Map of words equivalent based on integer value
  val WordsLookup = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three", 4 -> "four", 5 -> "five",
    6 -> "six", 7 -> "seven", 8 -> "eight", 9 -> "nine", 10 -> "ten", 11 -> "eleven",
    12 -> "twelve", 13 -> "thirteen", 14 -> "fourteen", 16 -> "sixteen", 17 -> "seventeen",
    18 -> "eighteen", 19 -> "nineteen", 20 -> "twenty", 21 -> "twenty one", 22 -> "twenty two",
    23 -> "twenty three", 24 -> "twenty four", 25 -> "twenty five", 26 -> "twenty six",
    27 -> "twenty seven", 28 -> "twenty eight", 29 -> "twenty nine")

  // a Map of time periods
  val PeriodLookup = Map(1 -> "before midday", 2 -> "after midday")

  def TimeAsWords(InputTime: String, Exp24hr: String,
                  WordsLookup: Map[Int, String], PeriodLookup: Map[Int, String]) = {

    def ExtractTime(InputTime: String, PeriodLookup: Map[Int, String]): (Int, Int, String) = {
      // extract 12hours, minutes and period from input string
      val HrsInt = InputTime.take(2).toInt
      val Hrs12Int = 12 - ((-HrsInt % 12) + 12) % 12
      val MinInt = InputTime.takeRight(2).toInt
      val PdString = if (HrsInt <= 12) PeriodLookup(1) else PeriodLookup(2)
      Tuple3(Hrs12Int, MinInt, PdString)
    }
    def ConvertTime(WordsLookup: Map[Int, String], hours: Int, minutes: Int, period: String) = {
      // Convert Hours12, Minutes and Period into Time As Words
      // using WordsLookup Map and conditional expressions, return the appropriate string
    }
    // validate format, convert to words else return error message
    if (InputTime.matches(Exp24hr)) {
      val (hours, minutes, period) = ExtractTime(InputTime, PeriodLookup)
      // temporary for testing output results
      println(hours + ":" + minutes + " - " + period)
      val TimeString = ConvertTime(WordsLookup, hours, minutes, period)
//      println(TimeString)
    } else {
      println("Input String doesn't match required format: 00:00 - 23:59")
    }
  }
  TimeAsWords(InputTime, Exp24hr, WordsLookup, PeriodLookup)
}
```

Comment: You might consider taking this excellent question to a better forum, like [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I'll have a look at codereview.

Comment: @ShawnMehan The [question has been closed as off-topic on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165839/convert-time-24hr-format-into-time-as-words), since the Scala implementation is not working. (The `ConvertTime()` function is unimplemented.)

Comment: Therefore does that not mean that the better question here is "how to fix ConvertTime()"?

Comment: Hi @200_success, I'll edit the following and add my current view on how I see it should be implemented by breaking it out into separate functions.

Comment: Hi @200_success. I've updated my question on Code Review, and uploaded a working version of  my Scala Object